# Contact Form 7 Plugin (Wordpress) - Catch date from page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to insert a contact form on an event, so the user can register to that event. I don't want to generate a contact form for each event, so my idea is to catch the date from a site element

Date:

```
<span class="ecwd-event-date" itemprop="startDate" content="2017-06-22T18:00">                                        22.06.2017 18:00  - 13.07.2017 21:30                                 </span>
```

Subject:

```
<h1 itemprop="name" class="ecwd-events-single-event-title summary entry-title">subject</h1>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-database/ . This will let you keep a db record of the submission with a timestamp. Rather than the form generating the timestamp, the DB will generate it when the user submits the form.

Comment: Thank you! Problem is: I don't need to catch the current date, I need to catch the event title and event date. I can't differentiate for which event the user has registered with a timestamp.

Comment: I need something like 
<?php echo '<div class="ecwd-event-date">' ?> inside the contact form. (don't know if echo is the right thing here....it should insert the data of the div in the contact form input)

Comment: Or maybe a variation of this: http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-counter-for-contact-form-7
..?

Comment: solved it via JS:


[code]
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByName('date-920')[0].value = document.getElementsByClassName('ecwd-event-date')[0].innerText;
document.getElementsByName('kurs')[0].value = document.getElementsByClassName('ecwd-events-single-event-title summary entry-title')[0].innerText;
</script>[/code]